# Run command on host before containers start in docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I need to run a command (chmod 777 -R $PWD) to change the permissions of the current host directory, which is bind-mounted, just before the container (dummyservice1) starts through the docker-compose. There is no way to do it from within the container as it requires root privileges. Is there a way to execute this command just before the actual containers start?

docker-compose.yaml :

```
version: '3'
services:
  dummyservice1:
    image: XXX
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/aaa/bbb
    environment:
      - ENV_VAR=someVal

  dummyservice2:
    image: YYY
    volumes:
      - $PWD:/aaa/bbb
    environment:
      - ENV_VAR=someOtherVal
    depends_on:
      - dummyservice1
```

Comment: (Setting anything to mode 0777 is usually a security mistake.  What's actually in this directory, and why do you need to change its permissions?  Do you need to instead set one of the containers to have a user or group ID that can write to a given host directory?)

Comment: @DavidMaze Yes I can do with changing owner of host directory to "app" . But even in that case I will need to run the chown command on host before the actual container starts. Any way this can be achieved?

Comment: Set the containers' `user:` to match the numeric user ID that owns the host directory.